# Pandas DF counter

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a pandas df

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Asd |
| 1 | Thy |
| 1 | fhj |
| 2 | khh |
| 2 | ytr |
| 3 | hgj |

I want to have a counter column c based on the grouped values of A.
Expected Output:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Asd | 1 |
| 1 | Thy | 2 |
| 1 | fhj | 3 |
| 2 | khh | 1 |
| 2 | ytr | 2 |
| 3 | hgj | 1 |

Sample output provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.groupby` + `.cumcount`:

```py
df["C"] = df.groupby("A").cumcount() + 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A    B  C
0  1  Asd  1
1  1  Thy  2
2  1  fhj  3
3  2  khh  1
4  2  ytr  2
5  3  hgj  1
```